# Disable or slow down dynamic search in transaction screens

Tags: acumatica

Is there some way to slow down or disable the dynamic search that occurs on master data fields in transaction screens?  For example, when looking up a customer or item on a sales order the system will start to search for a customer or item if you pause or type slow.  Several of our clients have found the live search to cause errors because the wrong item is chosen when the search list pops up or the list can be confusing for a user who types slow.
Thanks,
Kurt